# Aspnet Core - Application Started event

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, application-lifecycle

I am trying to find an event that notify that and aspnet core application is now ready to server http requests.

I tried to use the `IApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted` but the event is raised before the application is ready to handle requests.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've always seen this as an external thing (the load balancer or provisioner) hitting a health check.  It seems core does have easy to implement health checks very recently and currently in preview: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2018/08/22/asp-net-core-2-2-0-preview1-healthcheck/

Comment: Hello, this is not really what I am looking for. I am trying to get events that inform me of the lifecycle of startup process.